# sumif function in R of two matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices with timeseries data

```
A
2 1 0
0 1 6
1 4 6

B 
1 1 3
4 2 8
2 5 1
```

I want to create a vector comparing A and B and satisfying the following criteria:

if B<3, then sum the elements of A by row that follow the criteria
So my result matrix should be

```
C
3 (=2+1)
1
7 (=1+6)
```

I have tried to do it the following way but I was not able to get the proper results

```
posneg_fun<-function(x,y)
{
  new<-sum(x[y<3])
  return(new)
}

out<-t(apply(x,1,FUN=posneg_fun,y))
```

any ideas?

thank you

Comment: if you feel the answer posted below solves your problem, you should consider clicking the check-mark to accept it ...

Comment: just did! thank you for letting me know, i was not aware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
A[B>=3] <- NA
rowSums(A,na.rm=TRUE)
## [1] 3 1 7
```

or @Roland's suggestion (even shorter):

```
rowSums(A*(B<3))
```

which takes advantage of the fact that `TRUE` gets coerced to 1 and `FALSE` gets coerced to 0 when doing numerical operations ...